# Evaluating non-latin characters which are created by a combination of keystrokes

Tags: swift, string, cocoa, unicode, appkit

Our app compares an expected string, against what the user is typing and only allows expected characters to appear.

So, given an expected string: 
foo

The app evaluates each characters like so:

```
Type f
Is typed char (case & diacritic insensitive)f?
  yes? do nothing
  no?  remove 1 char from string
```

This works wonderfully for latin characters. However, as soon as you hit non latin characters (such as Thai or Kanji) things turn to custard. 
Specifically:

Some non-latin characters appear to be typed by a combination of characters, so

```
Is typed char (case & diacritic insensitive)ยั?
```

is always false, because it appears that `ยั` is typed ย  ั

That also causes problem, because

```
remove 1 char from string
```

isn't reliable, because some non-latin chars have a `Range` length of >1 in Swift (this isn't too hard to fix).

For case & diacritics, `æ` and `œ` I just search case and diacritic insensitive (so typing `e` makes `é` appear if it is the next expected character, or typing `a` makes `æ` appear if it is next expected). This works well, and I was hoping there was a way I could do something similar with [the entire world of non-latin character sets] .

How can I practically compare an expected character (such as `ยั`) with user intent (`ย`) in AppKit or with Swift? I don't have the language to express the problem, but basically "*Is the character just typed a character that can, when combined with another character, create the expected (composed unicode) character?*"